# Reference Request: Dummbatz

Tags: etymology, spelling, slang, reference-request

Can anybody confirm that *Dummbatz* is Saxon dialect (or perhaps low Saxon)?

I heard it from a friend repeatedly,  whose father was from around Dresden, said *Pfenge, ei verbibbsch* and so on. I parsed it as *-batz[en]*. It means what it says on the tin, and is interesting because *dumb-ass* is so close.

A websearch shows the word has some currency. There's an entry in e.g. [Mittelelbisches Wörterbuch](https://mew.uzi.uni-halle.de/artikel/7817), Mundmische, en.wiktionary. I'm worried it's a loan from English, but that aside, I suspect it indirectly continued Germanic *-az, or *-anaz through reinterpretation.

Immediately it would be therefore enough to exclude it were a loan.

Comment: Wird es "Duhmbatz" oder "Dummbatz" gesprochen?

Comment: @userunknown Ich kenne es als Dummbatz.

Comment: naja, einerseits war da ein Freud'scher Versprecher im Spiel, der die Bezugnahme auf das englische vorweggenommen hat, andererseits ist der Zusammenhang zu *tumb*, *taub*, *doof* auch nicht ganz von der Hand zu weisen. Für die Suchmaschinen habe ich es mal angepasst. @userunknown mit *doom* hat es glaube ich nicht's zu tun. Die Vokallänge ist wie in *Mus*, sag ich mal, recht unvoreingenommen :P Ich höre natürlich *dumm*, aber das ist nicht entscheidend.

Comment: @vectory Ich glaube nicht das _Dummbatz_ ein spezifisch sächsischer Dialektausdruck ist. Das ist (leider) weiter verbreitet.

Comment: @vectory: Eine Schreibweise "doombass" wollte ich nicht nahelegen - oft genug habe ich dumbass geschrieben gelesen. Es ging mir um die Aussprache von Dumbatz (deswegen auch "batz", nicht "bass"). Mus wie in Apfelmus ist aber lang; dennoch hast Du es jetzt zu Dummbatz geändert? Und du hörst "dumm" - also wie jetzt - :verwirrt:. ;)

Comment: Das gibt's auch in anderen Bundesländern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das [Rheinische Wörterbuch](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=RhWB&lemid=RB01711) kennt den Batz und schreibt zu Batz:

> m.: starker, frecher Kerl, der sich seiner Kräfte bewusst ist u. damit
>   prahlt, frecher Prahler u. Streitsucher. Ene B. van em Jong Du freiche
>   B.; bes. auf halbwüchsige Jungen angewandt.

Ich bin aber schon zu lange aus der Gegend weg, um aus der Erinnerung sagen zu können, ob Dummbatz dort (noch) gebräuchlich ist. Jedenfalls ist es ein gutes Stück von Sachsen entfernt.

Apfelbatz für das Kerngehäuse jedenfalls war in meiner Jugend gängig.

Die [Wörterbuchsuche](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/startGlobalSearch.tcl?stichwort=Batz) des Wörterbuchnetzes ist aber allgemein eine gute Hilfe, wenn man sich das Leben schwer machen will (umfangreich, detailreich, teils schwer zu lesen). Für Sachsen haben sie aber (bislang) kein Wörterbuch.

Das "b" in tumb lässt vielleicht eine Verbindung von tumb ~ dumm zu, aber dass man es deshalb zu Dumb - Atz trennen müsste/könnte kommt mir nicht plausibel vor. Auch eine Verbindung Atz - Arsch kenne/finde ich nicht. Eher könnte ich mir vorstellen, dass Deutschmuttersprachler "Dummbatz" in die Staaten (ins Angelsächsische bereits?) gebracht haben, aber die Herkunft vergessen wurde, und es sich dort dann zum plausibleren *dumbass* gewandelt hat. Das sind aber laienhafte Spekulationen.

Answer (score -1):

Seit @UserUnknown in seiner Antwort auf "Apfelbatz" hingewiesen, muss an dieser Stelle auf eine weitere Thematik eingegangen werden, die den Zugang zu *Dummbatz* leider erschwert.

Das Schweizerische Idiotikon kennt in der gleichen Bedeutung *Bitschgi* (s.d.), *Pütschi* usw. als Kerngehäuse, "Kernhaus der Äpfel, auch der Birnen" und zitiert Glossen, darunter "Pit" und "der Butz, Bütschge, umbilicus pomi, oculus piri" (Red. 1662 = Johann Jakob Redinger. Vestibulum scholasticae eruditionis), auch Metonym für den gesampten Apfel. Dabei muss "Pit" niederländisch sein, woraus amerikanisch *pit* "the stone of a fruit" entlehnt (etymonline.com, dictionary.com, "Americanism").

Damit ergibt sich imprinzip sofort ein Lösungansatz: *Dumm-Batz* dürfte *taube Nuss* entsprechen (vgl. engl. *dumb* "stumm* usw.), auch *Hohlbirne* usf. Doch das könnte Zufall sein.

Laut Phillipa *et al.* fehlen hochdeutsche Anschlüsse: "Het woord komt verder alleen voor in het Middelnederduits: *pit, pitte* ‘pit, kern’." Sowie die weitere Herkunft ungewiss ist: "Misschien is dit hetzelfde woord als mnl. *pedic* ‘houtmerg, pit’ [1300-50; MNW pedic], *[...] waarvan de verdere herkomst eveneens onbekend is." (etymologiebank.nl) Dennoch wird mit engl. *pith* eine west-germanische Wurzel konstruiert (ebenso etymonline.com), die wegen des *p nicht urgermanisch sein kann.

Weil daneben mehrere Onomatopoeia stehen, etwa *Putsch*, auch *Bütsch* ("heftiger Stoß, Puff, Anprall", Idiotikon), vergleichbar Pfeifer über *patschen* "ein klatschendes Geräusch machen", kann die Annahme "zur lautmalenden Interjektion" (DWDS) als Schutzbehauptung gelten. Auch *Batzen* "Klumpen" ist eine eher undefinierbare Menge, "Herkunft ungewiss" (DWDS).

Deshalb sei anhand des Konsonantenwechsels ferner auf *Tollpatsch* verwiesen:

> **Tolpatsch** m. ‘ungeschickter, täppischer Mensch’. Zuerst *Tolbatz* (obd. um 1700) ‘ungarischer Fußsoldat’ (der anstelle der Schuhe breite, mit Schnüren befestigte Sohlen trug), entlehnt aus ungar. *talpas* ‘breitsohlig, groß-, breitfüßig’, hier in seiner scherzhaften (heute veralteten) Substantivierung ‘Fußsoldat’, auch ‘Bär’ (abgeleitet von ungar. *talp* ‘Sohle, Tatze’). *[...]*

> Wolfgang Pfeifer et al., Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen (1993), digitalisierte und von Wolfgang Pfeifer überarbeitete Version im Digitalen Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/T%C3%B6lpel, abgerufen am 21.04.2023.

Darunter steht in Klammern: "(vielleicht unter Einfluß von *Tölpel* und *patschen*, s. d.)". Im allgemein sind Hinweise wie "scherzhaft" nur so zu verstehen, der geneigten Leserschaft sowie dem Autor selbst wäre der Witz nicht ersichtlich. Tatsächlich ist *talp* unbekannter Herkunft, häufig mit romänisch *talpă* verglichen, wobei ein ost-germanisches Substrat (Gepiden?) nicht auszuschließen ist (en.wiktionary)

Davon abgesehen steht in Frage, ob engl. *dumb-ass* dazu gehört, angenommen die Deutung *-ass* "Arsch" unterliege der Volksetymologie, was angesichts der Bedeutung jedenfalls nicht unwahrscheinlich ist. Dafür bieten sich zwei Vergleichsmöglichkeiten: Synonym *butt* und Synonym *dumb-bitch*, wozu ggf. *Petze* zu vergleichen wäre. Beides ist ungewiss.

Bemerkenswerter Weise entspricht einer von mehreren Ansätzen (etymonline.com: *butt*), nämlich altfranzösisch *bot* "end, extremity", ungefähr auch Russisch тельпу́х "block or stump from a tree", das aus dem oben angegebenen romänischen Wort hervorgegangen sein soll, so wohl auch Bairisch *Tälpen* "rootstocks" (en.wiktionary). Dabei soll *bot* aus germanisch **butt* "stumpf" entlehnt sein, darunter unter anderem in der Bedeutung "Klumpfuß", "personne qui a le pied bot" und "Holzschuh" (FEW). Dagegen fällt der Unterschied zu dem zweiten Ansatz, nämlich altenglisch *buttuc "end, small piece of land", altnordisch *botr* "short" (etymonline.com) bzw. "kurzes Stück eines Holzstammes" (FEW: **butr* "Holzklotz") doch eher gering aus. Meiner bescheidenen Meinung nach ist auch euphemistisch *Hosenboden* sowie portugiesisch *bunda* kaum davon zu trennen; hilft aber auch nicht weiter. Es wäre angesichts der Unsicherheit nicht gänzlich abwegig, auf eine vorgermanische Form aus **pod-* "Fuß" abzustellen (lat. *pes* ~ *pedes*, agr. πούς ~  ποδός, einerseits ἀμφοῖν ποδοῖν, *etc.*, "to denote energetic action" [lsj], andererseits ungeklärt ἀνδράποδον, Ep.dat.pl. ἀνδραπόδεσσι *(as if from ἀνδράπους)* [lsj], auch πούς "boundary stone", ferner πέδον "ground, earth", "of a particular site, especially of sacred ground" [lsj], "Orig. meaning trace, bottom, from the word for foot" [Frisk]).

Zwar bleibt *talp* dennoch unerklärt, doch das ist unerheblich, denn für die Annahme der scherzhaften (als ob) Beleidigung ist der Unterschied zwischen *talpas* und *talbatz* unerklärlich.

Kurzer Einschub: Hebräisch בֵּיצָה *betzá* heißt auch Pimmel. Das ist doch fürn Fuß alles wieder hier.

*[Fortsetzung folgt]*